Does Nginx uses consistent hashing with Virtual nodes for load balancing using hash / ip_hash
Under ngx_http_upstream_module module we have hash and ip_hash directive which is used to route requests from same client to a single pod every time using client's ip or any other key. These directives uses consistent hashing to distribute the load to dynamic set of servers/pods. On the internet I read that just consistent hashing alone doesn't lead to uniform distribution of load, so Virtual nodes are introduced to improve uniform distribution and to prevent skewing hotspots.
My question is, Does nginx uses this virtual Node variation to uniformly distribute the load while using consistent hashing ? Couldn't find any document/page supporting its use or otherwise anywhere.
